# project is not opening from your projects directory in wamp server even it is showing

Tags: localhost, wampserver

Can't open the project from your project directory in WAMP SERVER.....although the project name is showing there when i click on it the message displayed is "Unable to connect to internet"

Comment: Have you disabled networking?

Answer (score 6):

In your "www" folder, open index.php and change line 30 from

```
$suppress_localhost = true;
```

to

```
$suppress_localhost = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `www` folder, open `index.php` and change line 33 from

```
$suppress_localhost = ($wampConf['urlAddLocalhost'] == 'off' ? true : false);
```

to

```
$suppress_localhost = ($wampConf['urlAddLocalhost'] == 'on' ? true : false);
```

Comment: You should be giving some explanation too!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the taskbar wamp icon, in the wamp setting, enable "Add localhost in url".

Don't mess up the index.php configurations with hardcoded thingies. It works but it may backfire in future.